# PHP : understanding each function with array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am  doing some basic PHP stuff from a book and in arrays section I got this example:

```
$array=  array('Books '=>3 , 'Pens' => 4);
while ($element= each($array)){
    echo $element[0].' - '. $element[1].'<br/>';
}
```

So this is the output:

```
Books - 3
Pens - 4
```

My question is that when we parse this array in loop does it return every element as array? I mean   **$element[0]**  is index 0 and **$element[1]** is index 1 for Books and then for Pens or its key pair value?

Comment: Please read manuals - http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [each()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php). It returns an array of the current key / value pair and uses indexes 0 and 1 as well as indexes `key` and `value`:

```
echo $element['key'].' - '. $element['value'].'<br/>';
```

The same can be done in a more visible way using list which assigns an array to variables:

```
$array =  array('Books '=>3 , 'Pens' => 4);

while (list($key, $val) = each($array)){
    echo "Key is $key and Value is $val<br/>";
}
```

[foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is more commanly used:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    echo "Key is $key and Value is $val<br/>";
}
```

Comment: so each item is itself an array ?

Comment: Not in the original array.  `each()` extracts the key and value and returns it as an array.